# Terminal: Recursively search directory of aliases with "find” command

Tags: macos, terminal, alias

Probably answered in some I don't know to search for.  I am using

`find ~/. -type f | wc -l`

as a quick-and-dirty way to count files.

Can I get Terminal to search macOS aliases as if they were hard links (I think - macOS doesn't let you hard link directories, so I can't test it).  And I can use -prune to exclude ".app" (application) directories?

Comment: An alias is a Finder convention, not a macOS (Unix) one. Try using `mdfind kMDItemKind="Alias"`

Comment: `mdfind -onlyin ~ kMDItemKind="Alias"` to mimic the `find` command from the question.

Comment: Are you trying to search the things aliases point to as if they were subdirectories? If so, that's a lot harder. I don't know of any (built-in) command line tools to resolve aliases. You might have to use `osascript` to run some AppleScript to get Finder to resolve them for you, or something similarly unweildy.